# Why {a:1}['a'] equals ['a'] and console.log( {a:1}['a'] ) equals 1?

Tags: javascript, object

Why does {a:1}['a'] equals ['a'] and console.log( {a:1}['a'] ) equals 1?
I tried in node 13.8 and chrome.

Comment: `{a:1}['a']` equals `['a']`. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @MaheerAli He means that when you enter the statement `{a:1}['a']` in the devtools console, you get back an array.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. I just don't understand this behavior.

Comment: @HankWang The second duplicate link should have the most insight for your case